# Three vectors giving resultant 0, but not forming a triangle?

Tags: vectors, triangles

There's this statement in one of my books that says,

> In general, for any non-zero vectors $\overrightarrow{a}$, $\overrightarrow{b}$, and $\overrightarrow{c}$, one may note thst although $\overrightarrow{a}+ \overrightarrow{b}+\overrightarrow{c}=0$, they may not always represent the sides of a triangle.

This seems confusing. If I take three vectors, and consider just two of them, I'll get a resultant vector, which can only be cancelled out by another vector parallel to it in the opposite direction, implying that all three *have* to lie on a triangle. That's the general consensus on three non-zero vectors giving zero resultant that I know of, too.

Is there a case I'm missing here?

Comment: Maybe they don't count it as a "triangle" if $a, b, c$ are on the same line?

Comment: I agree with Yuval. Such "naming" claim also highly depends on the context. If the underlying field for the vectors isn't $\mathbb{R}$, personally I would not call such triple a triangle.

Comment: @Yuval: That explains it nicely. Wonder why the book didn't specify this, because it seemed almost intentionally vague, like there were lots of cases left out. Don't get me wrong; this answers the question, but are you sure there aren't any more cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP: “*@Yuval, that explains it nicely. Wonder why the book didn't specify this, because it seemed almost intentionally vague, like there were lots of cases left out... are you sure there aren't any more cases?*”

- Suppose that $\mathbf a,\mathbf b,\mathbf c$ aren't collinear (i.e., aren't
  parallel).

  Then, since $\mathbf a,\mathbf b,\mathbf c$ are nonzero and sum to
  $\mathbf 0,$ no pair is collinear; in particular, $\mathbf a
     \nparallel \mathbf b.$

  Thus, $0^{\circ}<\text{angle between }\mathbf a \:\&\: \mathbf b
     <180^{\circ}.$

  Since $\mathbf a+\mathbf b+\mathbf c=\mathbf 0,$ the three vectors
  form a triangle.
- Therefore, if the three vectors *don't* form a triangle, then they
  *must* be collinear. In this case, the three vectors in fact form a [degenerate triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(mathematics)).

Comment: Nice, concise answer. I hope I haven't missed out on any logic here, though, because it seems trivial, atleast looking at the cases we've considered.